# Customize redirection after login function Post_Login

Tags: oracle, url, url-rewriting, oracle-apex

I have an apex app. I have done some work on URL rewritings in order to make the URL's user friendly. Actually it works pretty well even on private pages (my app has a personal space). I just type **www.domain.com/PageAlias** and the server loads internally the page : **www.domain.com/apex/f?p=AppID:PageID:SessionID** (the session is preserved properly)

I still have only one problem left on the redirection after the login. I'm using custom authentication.

```
Wwv_Flow_Custom_Auth_Std.Post_Login(p_uname => :p101_username , p_password => :p101_password, p_session_id => v('APP_SESSION'), P_Flow_page => 'MyAppName:MyPageName');
```

When the user connects, the redirection works but with the app id and the page id. The page opened right after the login has the ugly URL **www.domain.com/apex/f?p=AppID:PageID:SessionID**

I was wondering if there is another way to redirect the user after login to a custom URL. I would love to have **www.domain.com/PageAlias** as redirection after login

Actually it's the only page I still have an ugly url for.

Does anyone have a idea please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade to APEX 20.1 then you can utilize the new Friendly URLs feature. Alternatively, you can easily redirect to any URL using apex_util.redirect_url API